# Updated software from 2.2 to 2.2.2 and now my computer can't see my phone

Tags: android, eclipse

I updated my phone software from 2.2 to 2.2.2 and now eclipse cannot see that my phone is connected even when I go to manual run configurations, my phone does not show up.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

OS is 11.10 Ubuntu and the phone is HTC Desire
Software wouldn't update everything. Hmm, maybe I will have to try uninstalling and see if that works.

Comment: What kind of phone?
Which OS on your PC?

Comment: OS is 11.10 Ubuntu and the phone is HTC Desire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed usb ports and now it works. This guy seemed to have a similar problem:
[ADB doesn't see my USB-connected device anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547656/adb-doesnt-see-my-usb-connected-device-anymore/8547960#8547960)