# ADB doesn't see my USB-connected device anymore

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I recently upgraded my (Windows 7) development environment to Eclipse 3.7.1 (Indigo). I have an HTC Magic (Rogers) running Android 2.1upd8.1, a Kobo Vox running 2.3.3 and a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running 3.1. Only the Galaxy is visible as a USB connected device. [Previously, under helios and Ganymede, I had no problem finding and testing on the HTC! Also, I have no problem executing on any compliant virtual device under the current indigo setup.]

Does anyone have any ideas what the problem might be with the HTC and/or the Kobo Vox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had a problem with my computer detecting my HTC Desire after upgrading. I switched USB ports and now it detects it.

You can also try to update the software on your pc.

Comment: See above for complete rationale.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Windows, while your device is plugged in:

```
click Start > Right-click My Computer > Manage

It will open Computer Management.

Click on System Tools > Device Manager.

Expand the Universal Serial Bus controllers node from the center frame.

Identify your android device:
Look for yellow-exclamation-mark icons or a name like Android device/HTC something;

Right-click > Uninstall.
```

The drivers will be uninstalled and the device will be unrecognised again.

Take out the wire and reconnect it; This time Windows will look for the drivers again (as if it were new) and then it should be installed correctly once again.

The reason it should work in another USB port but not the  original one is because the drivers were installed for that port only; if the drivers move, change or go missing it corrupts the installation; but the installation is only remembered on that USB port anyway.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I was about to try that but I wasn't sure about loosing the driver I had. You convinced me to try it. Works fine now.